# Use of assimilate vs imitate in a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Today I took an English test , in which I was asked to choose between **assimilate** and **imitate**  as a word which closely resembles the  phrase ‘to make a copy of’. I chose assimilate , because in my opinion imitate means ‘to copy someone or something’ . It probably does not stand for ‘to make a copy of’ . The word assimilate , in my opinion is very close to ‘to make a copy of’. I also saw the definition of assimilate in the Collins English Dictionary , which has one of the meanings as :

“to become or cause to become similar.”

According to me , the difference between the definition of ‘assimilate’ and ‘imitate’ is that when we use imitate , we do not ‘make a copy of something’ , we ‘try to copy that thing’. However , there is quite similarity between these two meanings and I would like to know your opinion on which choice is really correct.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Assimilate" does not mean "to make a copy of".  These are the primary definitions:

> [**assimilate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assimilate) (v):
>   1a. to take into the mind and thoroughly understand
>   1b. to take in and utilize as nourishment : to absorb into the system
>   2. to absorb into the cultural tradition of a population or group

Apparently it can mean something like "to make similar", but to me this feels awkward and forced, and almost certainly would be confused with one of the primary definitions.  In this example sentence (from the dictionary link), I understand from context what the writer is trying to say, but I don't understand why Joseph Conrad chose to use this particular phrasing:

> [The capacity for detachment is] the only faculty that seems to **assimilate** man to the immortal gods.

However, even here I suspect the meaning is more to *be* similar rather than to *make* similar.  It's saying that this characteristic (of detachment) *likens* men to gods rather than *turns them into* gods.

Either way, I would not think "assimilate" a very good word to mean "copy" ... but then "imitate" is not such a good choice either.  Not because the definition is *wrong* but because it has generally *negative* connotations.  People *imitate* others either to mock them, or because they lack original thought.

If you wish to say that you intend to deliberately repeat something that someone else has already done (such as an experiment), try *repeat*, *reproduce*, *duplicate*, or *replicate*.

If you want a word that means to recreate in the style of, but less negative than imitate, try *emulate*, *mirror*, *echo*, or in some cases *simulate*.

Otherwise if you just want to make an exact copy something (like a document), use *copy*, *duplicate*, *clone*, or *replicate*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer , but what would be the best choice between assimilate and imitate for the phrase ‘to make a copy of’?

Comment: @Aditi  As I said, neither is correct.  I can't give you a good answer to a bad question.

Comment: I suspect the question setter thinks *imitate* can be used to mean *make an imitation of*.

Comment: @SamBC  which it does, certainly, but then you still have the same negative connotations with *imitation*, which generally means "fake".  **Imitation** crab is made from whitefish and seasonings, for example, and is tasty in its own way, but it's still not *real* crab.

Comment: Around here it's called "seafood sticks".